# How to add an encryption key to zip file header?

Tags: java, encryption, zip

I'm trying to find how to add information to zip file header in JAVA.

I want to know if it's possible to do that ?

The file header will be construct like this :
- The first 256 bytes correspond to the AES key encrypted with the RSA public key
- The following bytes correspond to the encrypted ZIP file with the AES key

Thanks !

Comment: `I want to know if it's possible to do that ?` following [.ZIP File Format Specification 5.2](https://pkware.cachefly.net/webdocs/APPNOTE/APPNOTE-5.2.0.txt) it's possible. Extra field with header ID 0x0017 is forseen for this use case.

Comment: Thanks for you reply but it's a paying package if I'm not wrong

Comment: Your question was, if it's possible. Following the ZIP specs it is possible even in the default ZIP implementation. There are other proprietary solutions (e.g. WinZIP) which might lead to compatibility problems. Out of the box Java doesn't support it.